# How to merge all cases report into one final report?

Tags: robotframework

I understand there is command to merge :

```
rebot --merge TC002-002output.xml rerunTC002-002output.xml
```

however i have about 50 single report to merge, is there better quicker way to merge them.
the structure as follow

```
Output\TC001.xml .....TC020.xml
Output\NEW\TC030.xml.....TC050.xml
```

Comment: I dont understand, you want to merge them into one single report? You can merge multiple files using rebot and it supports wildcards. If you want just one file, it can be simple one liner

Comment: @JiriJanous i have explained that i have many files, input them one by one in command line is not efficient.

Comment: That is where the wildcards come in to play. You can write for example rebot --merge TC* rerunTC*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rebot CLI API](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.html?highlight=run_cli#robot.rebot.rebot_cli) to create a script that recursively collects all XML from a given folder and then merges them.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
from robot import rebot_cli


def collect_xmls(path, xmls):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        file_path = os.path.join(path,filename)
    
        if filename.endswith('.xml'):
            fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
            xmls.append(file_path)
        
        if os.path.isdir(filename):
            collect_xmls(file_path, xmls)

root_folder = sys.argv[1]
rebot_args = []
collect_xmls(root_folder, rebot_args)
rebot_cli(rebot_args)
```

Call it like: `python merge.py Output`. This script assumes that all XML is an output XML but you can add more check on file names.

Comment: the command python merge.py Output , is the name Output the final report? i can do python merge.py finaloutput.xml ?

Comment: sorry i am not very good in python. where should I paste the actual path to the script?

Comment: @guo I see you have accepted the answer. Are your previous comments still open? You can pass multiple args from command line `python merge.py Output finaloutput.xml`. Any parameters to rebot could go into `rebot_args = ['--merge', 'sys.argv[2]', 'param3']` then.
`Output`  in my example is the folder in which the xml can be found the merged output names will be default `log.html`, `report.html`, `output.xml`.

Comment: i got the error like Cannot merge outputs containing different root suites. Original suite is 'TC001-001' and merged is 'TC001-002'.
why?

Comment: @guo See my updated answer. You have to remove the `--merge` argument to be able to combine different test suites. Merging only applicable if you want to combine the results of the same suite. For more: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#merging-outputs

Comment: @guo What is not OK after removing the --merge?